# PHP MySQL multiple insert performance using pdo named parameters vs single sql line

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

Im using MySQL and PDO.
Is it faster to run a single query for multiple inserts (or update, delete) like this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
    (field1, field2, field3) 
VALUES 
    ('value1_1', 'value1_2', 'value1_3'), 
    ('value2_1', 'value2_2', 'value2_3'), 
    ('value3_1', 'value3_2', 'value3_3')
```

Or using named parameters like this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
    (field1, field2, field3) 
VALUES 
    (:value1, :value2, :value3)
```

And then adding the parameters like this:

```
<?php
    $stmt->bindParam(:value1, $value1); 
    $stmt->bindParam(:value2, $value2); 
    $stmt->bindParam(:value3, $value3); 

    $value1 = 'abc';
    $value2 = 'def';
    $value3 = 'ghj';

    $stmt->execute();

    $value1 = 'abc';
    $value2 = 'def';
    $value3 = 'ghj';

    $stmt->execute();

    $value1 = 'abc';
    $value2 = 'def';
    $value3 = 'ghj';

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Who cares about the performance here. If you're accepting user submitted data to insert, then it's bindParam all the way, no questions asked.

Comment: bindParam is secure for sure. And I don't understand, how you would combine first option with user input.

Comment: @user2791236 you read wrong

Comment: I think the real question is the difference in performance if you use a multiple insert like the first one, but still use placeholders. Then in theory you are executing 1 query vs 3 queries. Supposedly it's faster, but I haven't done the tests myself.